# ionic splash screen alert - Launching Application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am getting an alert when launching an ionic iOS app. The alert prompts the user during the splash screen (app loading) with 'Launching Application' See image attached. This is a new message that I have never seen before. Any ideas on the cause?

[image]

Comment: close application...rebuild everything and then try again.

Comment: alert is written in somewhere in .html file